# R: using map when output has different length than input

Tags: r, dictionary

The map functions transform their input by applying a function to each element of a list or atomic vector and returning an object of the same length as the input.

But how does one deal with a situation where the output has a different length than the input?

For example:

```
simulate <- function(x) rnorm(10, x, 1)
sapply(1:2, simulate)
```

This works, but when I try the same with map() instead of sapply(), I get an error message, namely:

"Error in map(1:2, simulate) : Formula or list of formulas required."

Answer (score 1):

May be the `map` used is not from `purrr`.  Load the package and if there are other package that mask the function, use `purrr::map`

```
library(purrr)
purrr::map(1:2, simulate)
[[1]]
 [1]  1.6140810 -0.1906985  1.3582205  0.8357189 -1.6083671  2.1074404  1.8567818 -1.4476759  0.9749724  1.7084030

[[2]]
 [1] 1.83648113 1.32697695 1.87202331 1.86865706 3.21617258 1.66576414 2.87320975 0.81623944 0.09391478 1.95562983
```